# How to get longitude and latiitude from Mapcomponent in codenameone?

Tags: dictionary, location

How to get longitude and latiitude of the point from Mapcomponent in codenameone when user click on certain on the component ?

I have to take user's location(longitude , latitude ,...) when user double click on map and please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getCoordFromPosition(x, y)` which will return a `Coord` object from which you can extract the lat/lon values. Notice that you can also use the new native maps API which is a bit different http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/03/mapping-natively.html

Comment: how can the values of x and y can be taken?

Comment: getPointFromCoord FYI its good form to accept a correct answer